# What are the special character in file name Ubuntu rsyslog while receiving logs from Zscaler?

Tags: rsyslog

I have configured Zscaler NSS log forward to send logs on Linux server which is using ubuntu rsyslog service, I am able to receive logs, however, file name which getting generated it's with Special character, which is causing an issue to copy via script. Below is nss.conf file created under /etc/rsyslog.d/nss.conf

```
            template(name="TmplMsg" type="list") {
                 constant(value="/rsys/log/client_logs/")
                 property(name="hostname")
                 constant(value="/")
                 property(name="programname" SecurePath="replace")
                 constant(value=".log")
                                     }

       template(name="TmplAuth" type="list") {
              constant(value="/rsys/log/client_logs/")
              property(name="hostname")
              constant(value="/")
             property(name="programname" SecurePath="replace")
             constant(value=".log")
                             }
                 authpriv.* ?TmplAuth
                    *.info;mail.none;authpriv.none;cron.none ?TmplMsg
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the [templates](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/master/configuration/templates.html) doc, as well as `securepath="replace"`, which replaces "/" in the property by "_", you can also use `controlcharacters=`. This can have one of 3 values:

1. `"escape"` to replace non-printing characters by `#ddd` (3 digit decimal value),
2. `"drop"` to remove them
3. or `"space"` to replace them by a space.